# What type of statistical test should I use?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

I am doing a research project where I am comparing the discrimination men and women face in the workplace.  I have participants answering questions where they rank their responses from 1 to 6 (strongly disagree to strongly agree).  Since I am examining the differences between two groups and not testing the same participants more than once  then the test I should use is a t test for independent samples?  I am not sure if I should be using a different type or t-test and/or if my logic for choosing this test is correct.

Comment: The Mann$-$Whitney $U$ test is the non$-$parametric equivalent of the independent sample $t-$test and is often used when the data isn't normal (e.g. when your data is likert ordinal as in the example you provided.)

Answer (score 1):

Categorical responses from 1 to 6 are routinely shown not to satisfy the normality assumption of $t$-tests, so I would avoid a $t$-test if possible. A non-parametric test such as a permutation test (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_(statistics)) is much more rigorous.